# Device is not showing in DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse, device, ddms

I am developing a android application which is running perfectly in motorola CLIQ(i installed driver for this).But it is not working in Samsung galaxy phone(I have not installed driver for this phone).I think driver is not needed for this.Any idea or help ?

Comment: Am also using Samsung Galaxy S2. In my DDMS the device displaying perfectly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You need to install the driver from the manufacture to debug codes in your device.
2. Make sure in Settings->Application->Development, tick the "USB debugging" choice.

Comment: Correct, for Samsung Galaxy serial phone, The USB driver is usually installed along with Kies, so you don't need install it separately.

Comment: I have already checked USB debugging, also didn't get any driver for My Samsung Galaxy Note , Model NO - GT-N7000, still looking for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Why you have to install the driver for every android device that you want to work with. Install the driver and then check how many devices are attached to the PC by using below command:

**`adb devices`**    // list all the attached devices

Follow the 4th step mentioned here: [Set up your system to detect your device.](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my phone (via usb) used to show up in Eclipse DDMS, but after few days it just disappeared. I had to open my command line tool, and type

```
adb kill-server
adb usb
```

And my phone appeared on DDMS devices window once again!

Comment: Go to your sdk directory (which you should've downloaded from Google), sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

Answer (score 1):

To access these settings, open the Developer options in the system Settings. On Android 4.2 and higher, the Developer options screen is hidden by default. To make it visible, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I had to root the device, after which DDMS logs started showing up as well as adb cmnd prompt performed "adb reboot" and other stuff.. phew..